# which is the meaning in MATLAB of the expression x=sum(1./mat(mat>0))?

Tags: matlab, matrix

i need an help on the following expression:

```
x=sum(1./mat(mat>0))
```

where mat is 45x45 matrix, and x is a resulting unique value. 
I don't know how the expression works on the matrix to result a unique value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try executing each term in the assignment to see what it does?

Comment: Check the chapter `logical indexing` of this [blog post](https://mathworks.com/de/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I can show you how it works

1. given `mat` like below

```
mat =

   0.32872  -0.82823  -0.28158   1.85967
   1.91667   0.80715   0.28686  -1.25210
   1.48839  -0.91152   0.31743   2.56112
  -0.58941   0.19372  -0.67827  -0.74609
```

2. run `mat > 0`, then you get

```
>> mat>0
ans =

  1  0  0  1
  1  1  1  0
  1  0  1  1
  0  1  0  0
```

which shows the logic value where `mat` entries is positive

3. run `mat(mat>0)` and you will get

```
>> mat(mat>0)
ans =

   0.32872
   1.91667
   1.48839
   0.80715
   0.19372
   0.28686
   0.31743
   1.85967
   2.56112
```

which extracts those positive entries from `mat`

4. run `1./mat(mat>0)` and you will get

```
>> 1./mat(mat>0)
ans =

   3.04213
   0.52174
   0.67187
   1.23892
   5.16198
   3.48598
   3.15035
   0.53773
   0.39045
```

which gives the element-wise reciprocal of those positive values

5. run `x = sum(1./mat(mat>0))` and you will get

```
>> x = sum(1./mat(mat>0))
x =  18.201
```

which gives the sum of reciprocals from the previous step

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!